# Unable to load multiple bitmaps - WinAPI

Tags: c++, winapi, bitmap

So recently I have been able to get my application to allow the user to load .bmp files from external directories. The application loads the picture just fine, but if the user highlights multiple pictures, my LoadImage() function complains and I think it's because it's getting multiple files at once so it doesn't know how to read them properly. (maybe).

Here's my Init function

```
void InitialiseDialog(HWND hwnd)
{
    ZeroMemory(&ofn, sizeof(ofn));
    ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(OPENFILENAME);
    ofn.hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    ofn.lpstrCustomFilter = NULL;
    ofn.nMaxCustFilter = 0;
    ofn.nFilterIndex = 0;
    ofn.nMaxFile = MAX_PATH;

    ofn.hwndOwner = hwnd;
    ofn.lpstrFile = file;
    ofn.lpstrFilter = TEXT("Bitmap Files (*.bmp)\0*.bmp\0\0");
    ofn.lpstrFileTitle = NULL;
    ofn.nMaxFileTitle = MAX_PATH;
    ofn.lpstrInitialDir = NULL;
    ofn.lpstrTitle = NULL;
    ofn.Flags = OFN_EXPLORER | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST | OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST | OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT;
    ofn.nFileOffset = 0;
    ofn.nFileExtension = 0;
    ofn.lpstrDefExt = NULL;
    ofn.lCustData = 0L;
    ofn.lpfnHook = NULL;
    ofn.lpTemplateName = NULL;
}
```

And here's how I'm loading bitmaps and calling things:

```
bool LoadAndBlitBitmap(LPCWSTR myFile, HDC hWinDC)
{
    // Load the bitmap image file
    hBitmap = (HBITMAP)::LoadImage(NULL, myFile, IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE);

    // Verify that the image was loaded
    if (hBitmap == NULL) {
        ::MessageBox(NULL, L"LoadImage Failed", L"Error", MB_OK);
        return false;
    }

    // Create a device context that is compatible with the window
    HDC hLocalDC;
    hLocalDC = ::CreateCompatibleDC(hWinDC);
    // Verify that the device context was created
    if (hLocalDC == NULL) {
        ::MessageBox(NULL, L"CreateCompatibleDC Failed", L"Error", MB_OK);
        return false;
    }

    // Get the bitmap's parameters and verify the get
    BITMAP qBitmap;
    int iReturn = GetObject(reinterpret_cast<HGDIOBJ>(hBitmap), sizeof(BITMAP),
        reinterpret_cast<LPVOID>(&qBitmap));
    if (!iReturn) {
        ::MessageBox(NULL, L"GetObject Failed", L"Error", MB_OK);
        return false;
    }

    // Select the loaded bitmap into the device context
    HBITMAP hOldBmp = (HBITMAP)::SelectObject(hLocalDC, hBitmap);
    if (hOldBmp == NULL) {
        ::MessageBox(NULL, L"SelectObject Failed", L"Error", MB_OK);
        return false;
    }

    // Blit the dc which holds the bitmap onto the window's dc
    BOOL qRetBlit = ::BitBlt(hWinDC, 0, 0, qBitmap.bmWidth, qBitmap.bmHeight,
        hLocalDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    if (!qRetBlit) {
        ::MessageBox(NULL, L"Blit Failed", L"Error", MB_OK);
        return false;
    }

    // Unitialize and deallocate resources
    ::SelectObject(hLocalDC, hOldBmp);
    ::DeleteDC(hLocalDC);
    ::DeleteObject(hBitmap);
    return true;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    int wmId, wmEvent;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        InitialiseDialog(hWnd);
        return 0;

    case WM_COMMAND:
        wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
        wmEvent = HIWORD(wParam);

        // Parse the menu selections:
        switch (wmId)
        {
        case ID_FILE_LOADIMAGES:
            if (GetOpenFileName(&ofn))
            {
                g_bhBitmap = !g_bhBitmap;
            }

            InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);
            return 0;

            break;
        case ID_FILE_LOADAUDIO:
            DestroyWindow(hWnd);
            break;
        case ID_FILE_EXIT:
            DestroyWindow(hWnd);
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        }
    case WM_PAINT:
        hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

        if (g_bhBitmap)
        {
            LoadAndBlitBitmap(file, hdc); // <-- Something not right about this...? 
        }

        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
```

The Output[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fALmw.png) (<-- Link does not open new tab so right-click and open new tab if you want to see the output, it's really just an error message...)

Thank you for reading my query. I'd greatly appreciate any help you could give me :) bye.

EDIT: Here are some variable definitions:

```
// Global Variables
HINSTANCE g_hInst;
HBITMAP hBitmap;
HDC hdc;
static OPENFILENAME ofn;
bool g_bhBitmap = false;
wchar_t file[1024];
```

Comment: Can you use a debugger and put a breakpoint on the MessageBox that is failing, so you can see the value of myFile?

Comment: where is `file` defined, and what is it's value

Comment: will  be much more useful if you show `GetLastError`  after `LoadImage` fail with `myFile` string

Comment: myFile is basically just a global wchar_t array, I posted extra information hope that's useful.

Comment: @FearlessHobbit - no - show in message box myFile and GetLastError

Comment: @FearlessHobbit Stackoverflow already has a mechanism for marking questions as duplicates (as it is the case for this one). It is not good practice to edit out the question.

Comment: Oh okay, I'm still pretty new to this site :) Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first suggestion would be to remove `OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT` from the flags.

If you keep it, you need to handle the case of the user selecting multiple files correctly.

From the manual:

> **OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT**
>
> The File Name list box allows multiple selections.
>
> If the user selects more than one file, the lpstrFile buffer returns
>   the path to the current directory followed by the file names of the
>   selected files.
>
> The nFileOffset member is the offset, in bytes or characters, to the
>   first file name, and the nFileExtension member is not used.
>
> The directory and file name strings are NULL separated, with an extra
>   NULL character after the last file name.

When you send that to

```
hBitmap = (HBITMAP)::LoadImage(NULL, myFile, IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
```

you are essentially trying to load a directory as a bitmap. Instead, you need to  individually create finenames for each selection, and load those separatly.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. Thing is, I need the OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT because I want the user to be able to load multiple images. How can I go about creating individual filenames for each selection? My WinAPI knowledge is not that advanced, I just want to achieve this basic functionality so that I can do something else to the application. The idea is to make an application that loads .bmp files concurrently using multi-threading.

Comment: `strcat` would be one option

Comment: Could you perhaps give me an example if it's not too much trouble please? I really don't know how or where to put that :(